# Besides a rebuild, how can you become native to Toril if you currently aren't?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, forgotten-realms, character-advancement

The sarrukh possesses the supernatural ability **manipulate form**. The ability is one of the game's most powerful and versatile and it's essential for the overpowered kobold [Pun-pun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134478/8610). However, the special ability says, "At will, a sarrukh can modify the form of any Scaled One **native to Toril**, except for aquatic and undead creatures" (*Serpent Kingdoms* 80–1 and emphasis mine).

Other than using the character rebuilding rules from *Player's Handbook II*, is there a way for a creature that's not native to Toril originally to become native to Toril later?

Official *3.5* material, nonupdated *Third Edition* material, and *Dragon* magazine material is fine, but third party material is not. Also, this question is about what *works* and not what's *balanced.* (I mean, it's a question about Pun-Pun, so I hope that was already clear!)

Comment: What is your interpretation of "native"?  Is it an attribute of the body?  An attribute of lived history?  Something else?

Comment: @Novak Whatever it is that manipulate form requires, as I specified in my last sentence.

Comment: I attempted to edit this for clarity when it was at 3 votes to hold. An hour after I did, it's up to 4 votes to hold for being unclear. Can users offer suggestions as to what could make this even clearer? (Note that there is a lack of clarity on the part of the special ability, but that's not the question's fault and, in fact, is kind of the point of the question!)

Answer (score 7):

Since it looks like you're going with the infinite wishes route, you could wish for [reincarnations](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reincarnate.htm) until you get a reptilian race. The spell doesn't state it, but it's just natural and reasonable to think you're reincarnating into a creature that's native to the plane you're casting the spell in, thus turning you into a valid target for the manipulate form.

> With this spell, you bring back a dead creature in another body.

[...]

> Since the dead creature is returning in a new body, all physical ills
>   and afflictions are repaired.  The magic of the spell creates an
>   entirely new   young adult body for the soul to inhabit from the
>   natural elements at hand.

[...]

> A reincarnated creature recalls the majority of its former life and 
>   form. It retains any class abilities, feats, or skill ranks it 
>   formerly possessed.

Answer (score -1):

First, it's not clear, because "native" is not well-defined.  There is a subtype of "native" that applies only to outsiders, but that's not what we're talking about here.  The term "native" here is just a matter of what your home plane is, and what exactly that means doesn't really get defined completely anywhere.

So... it's an ugly thing to say for a RAW question, but this looks like it's a matter for DM adjudication, because the rule on the matter simply isn't written.  Still, there are some things that quite reasonably might work.

- Wish can do anything, right?  "change my native plane for all purposes" sounds like a thing.  Similarly, Miracle might be able to pull it off with the right deity (a goddess of home and hearth and family, say).
- Reincarnate will form a new body for the dead target out of native soil.  That might well be enough... and then you can get a Yuan-Ti graft to qualify as a Scaled One.
- The psionic power Mind Switch True can be used to give you the body of your choice (taken from someone else).  If "native" is a matter of the body rather than the mind, that would probably suffice.

...and then there are various effects along similar but less promising lines that might work if these would work.  Still, at the end, it looks like it's DM's call (or if entirely without DM, then undefined).

Comment: could someone explain why I'm getting downvotes for this?

Comment: I think it's because the "native" here is not a reference to a creature type. It simply means "From a species originated in Toril". Also, if we're discussing rules crunching DM adjudication might not be a valid answer for some, the name of the game is go RAW.

Comment: @NameDisplay Huh.  Well, I knew the first part.  I've edited to make that more clear... and as for the second part, I don't think there *is* a RAW here.  I've edited to make it clearer that this is regrettable.