# Magic item to grant hands

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, content-identification

I can't remember the name or source but I'm looking for a set of magic gloves that were designed to be worn by creatures without hands on the end of  appendages that allowed those appendages to function as hands.

Comment: You may also be interested in answers to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147491/8610)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Try the *gloves of man*

I suspect you're remembering the ***gloves of man*** (*Savage Species* 57) (42,000 gp; 0 lbs.), the description of which, in part, says, "These magic gloves provide humanoid fingers and thumbs for the wearer. Any creature may wear them, provided the creature has tentacles or paws over which to slip them. While wearing the gloves, the creature may manipulate items as if it had fully functional hands."